# I can't find python json settings in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to edit python json settings to edit font size and stuff like that but whenever I open settings.json it opens something else

code:

```
{
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
    "*.assets": "default"
},
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.1",
"java.help.firstView": "gettingStarted",
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
},
"cSpell.ignoreWords": [

],
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro Darker",
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false,
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy `"editor.fontSize": 24` into your *setting.json* at the end for set the font-size to 24.

More about *settings.json* in **Visual Studio Code**, you can read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Comment: I got it now thank you